# Vue render component before data fetched

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vue-component

When i render my component with my data properties it loads html before data are fetched. This results in no data is shown. Until I make an api call inside the component with an a tag rendering the function.

Can anyone tell me how i render my component after data is fetched. I have tried the v-if condition. it renders my page with no data. If i remove the v-if it says can't read property of undefined.

```
  <div class="score">
          <p class="number">{{company.storeScore}} test</p>
          <p class="text">Tilfredhedscore</p>
  </div>

getStoreScore (condition) {
      return axios.post('API-LINK', {
        storeId: '5b7515ed5d53fa0020557447',
        condition: condition
      }).then(response => {
        this.company.storeScore = response.data.result
        this.company.amount = {
          'total': response.data.amount.total,
          'zero': {
            'amount': response.data.amount.zero,
            'percentage': (response.data.amount.zero !== 0 ? response.data.amount.zero / response.data.amount.total * 100 : 0)
          },
          'one': {
            'amount': response.data.amount.one,
            'percentage': (response.data.amount.one !== 0 ? response.data.amount.one / response.data.amount.total * 100 : 0)
          },
          'two': {
            'amount': response.data.amount.two,
            'percentage': (response.data.amount.two !== 0 ? response.data.amount.two / response.data.amount.total * 100 : 0)
          },
          'three': {
            'amount': response.data.amount.three,
            'percentage': (response.data.amount.three !== 0 ? response.data.amount.three / response.data.amount.total * 100 : 0)
          }

        }
      })
    }


data () {
    return {
      selected: 1,
      company: {},
      isActive: false,
      test12345: {}
    }
  },
```

[image: error message]

Thanks in advance

UPDATE (solved):
the company definition were null before like this

```
data() {
  return{
    company: null
  }
}
```

this caused problems with rendering out my data. 
the fix is to define the things in my array i want to use

e.g

```
data() {
  return{
    company: {
      amount: {
       total: null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties

you have to define a data object and set the values you load with ajax to make them reactive. in your case its only "company":

Comment: i have defined it in data :)   data () {
    return {
      selected: 1,
      company: {},
      isActive: false,
      test12345: {}
    }
  },

Comment: you only reference to total in the ajax call, so i guess response.data.amount is the problem

Comment: yes here https://hastebin.com/urakowufoq.xml

Comment: <p v-if="company.amount" class="number">{{this.company.amount.total}}</p>

I'd remove the "this" from here

Comment: Okay :) iv'e done that now, but it still comes with the error

Comment: ok, so the way vue works, it renders the whole template first, before doing any lifecycle event so whenever you write something like this

<p v-if="company.amount" class="number">{{company.amount.total}}</p>
it is trying to access "company.amount.total" because "company.amount" is defined as an empty object in data....

so change that to company: {total: null}

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked !

Answer (score 5):

That is great that you found solution yourself. Well i am proposing another solution.
You can use a Boolean to accomplish this.
Here is how:

```
data() {
  return{
    company: null,
    is_data_fetched: false
  }
}
```

And update this Boolean after data is fetched.

```
getStoreScore (condition) {
    return axios.post('API-LINK', {
        storeId: '5b7515ed5d53fa0020557447',
        condition: condition
    }).then(response => {
        this.company.storeScore = response.data.result;
        this.is_data_fetched = true;
    });
}
```

And then use this Boolean to stop rendering before data is fetched.

```
  <div class="score" v-if="is_data_fetched">
          <p class="number">{{company.storeScore}} test</p>
          <p class="text">Tilfredhedscore</p>
  </div>
```